# Null check on aggregate expression

Tags: c#, expression-trees

I have an expression helper to help getting values from object hierarchy

```
   public static Func<T, object> GetMemberExpressionFunc<T>(string expressionString)
   {
     if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(expressionString))
     {
         throw new InvalidOperationException("invalid Expression");
     }

     var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T));
     Expression memberExpression = parameter;
     var tokens = expressionString.Split('.');
     memberExpression = tokens.Aggregate(memberExpression, Expression.PropertyOrField);

     var convertExpression = Expression.Convert(memberExpression, typeof(object));
     return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, object>>(convertExpression, parameter)
                        .Compile();

    }
```

Usage

```
public class A
{
        public B BObj { get; set; }
}

public class B
{
        public string Name { get; set; }

}

 static void Main(string[] args)
 {
   var obj = new A {BObj = new B {Name ="Test"}};
   var obj2 = new A ();

   var exp = ExpressionHelper.GetMemberExpressionFunc<A>("BObj.Name");

  var test1 =  exp(obj);// test1 is "Test"

  var test2 = exp(obj2); //throws because BObj is null
}
```

I want the expression to return null if any property in the hierarchy is null instead of throwing exception. Is it possible to do this at the aggregate expression?

Comment: Do you understand what the Aggregate method is doing? As far as I can see it is just using the Linq `Aggregate` method to chain a bunch of `Expression.PropertyOrField` calls together. In theory you could pass in a different method that does the null check and then the chain but it might be tricky. I would think it would be more readable to just do it in a standard loop.

Comment: Yes, the main issue here is to return null when the property is null. Loop Vs aggregate readability is a matter of opinion, but I don't mind changing it if the actual problem can be solved.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

C# null conditional operator `?.` would have been very handy in this case. Unfortunately it's still not supported in expression trees, so one way to achieve the goal is to build dynamically the equivalent of manual null checks all down the road:

```
x => x != null && x.Prop1 != null && x.Prop1.Prop2 != null ... ? (object)x.Prop1.Prop2...PropN : null
```

Since you would need to aggregate both the member accessor expression and condition to be used in the final `Expression.Condition`, the `Aggregate` method is not good - doing the aggregation with the old good `foreach` loop looks more appropriate, for instance like this:

```
var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T));

var nullConst = Expression.Constant(null);
Expression source = parameter, condition = null;
foreach (var memberName in expressionString.Split('.'))
{
    var notNull = Expression.NotEqual(source, nullConst);
    condition = condition != null ? Expression.AndAlso(condition, notNull) : notNull;
    source = Expression.PropertyOrField(source, memberName);
}
source = Expression.Convert(source, typeof(object));
var body = Expression.Condition(condition, source, nullConst);

return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, object>>(body, parameter)
                   .Compile();
```